# php project in ubuntu. Correct paths but forbidden access

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

i'm trying to run a windows7 php project in ubuntu 12.04. i give the correct paths as i saw from web console but the css file and other files aren't used. The errors that web console shows are the following:

```
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/css/myCSSfile.css [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/css/search.css [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/css/button.css [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/css/button2.css [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/js/resolutionfinder.js [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/js/changeInputValue.js [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/js/ajaxcalls.js [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/js/ajaxcalls.js [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/images/logo.jpg [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
```

Someone told me that i have to check the .htaccess file to make sure i allow access to the css,js and images subdirectories but i'm actually new in ubuntu and i'm a bit confused about it. I use apache2 if that helps. thank you for your time.

If i write ps -ef | grep apache   on terminal the outcome is this

```
root      1058     1  0 20:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1067  1058  0 20:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1068  1058  0 20:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1070  1058  0 20:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1072  1058  0 20:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2431  1058  0 20:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2432  1058  0 20:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2433  1058  0 20:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2464  1058  0 20:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2465  1058  0 20:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2466  1058  0 20:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
manos     2541  2485  0 20:36 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

Also if i do cd cd /var/www  and then    ls -la
the outcome is this

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep  21 23:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Sep  23 13:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep  23 20:35 webserver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by wrong file permissions

As what user is Apache running?
You can check it with (in the terminal):

```
ps -ef | grep apache   (could also be running as 'httpd')
```

It might not have access to read/write the files of your project.
Check the file permissions in the

```
cd /var/www   (or what directory you have)
ls -la
```

Comment: I put the outcome of these commands in my question in case it helps. thnx for your time

Answer (score 1):

As Paul said the permissions in the root folder (/var/www) where wrong with this command everything is ok.

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /var/www
```

explanation of command:
The breakdown of permissions looks like this:

```
u – user

g – group

o – other
```

The 'other' entry is the dangerous one, as it effectively gives everyone permission for the folder/file. The permissions you can give to a file or folder are:

```
r – read

w – write

x – execute
```

Using the -R switch is important. If you have a number of sub-folders and files within the SHARE directory, and you want the permissions to apply from the parent object (the containing folder) to the child objects (the sub-folders and files), you must use the -R (recursive) switch so the same permissions are applied all the way to the deepest folder, contained within the parent.